# How can i change drop-down value in popup dropdown when i select from home page

Tags: jquery, dropdown, magento2

I have booking event functionality in magento 2.4.6. when I select booking start time after that when I click on book now button it show me booking start and end time and other details on popup but in booking start time it show me default 10 am time but i want to keep default select time which I have selected on home page.

I have used below jQuery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
require([
'jquery',
'domReady!'
], function ($)
 {
 
    $('#start-time').change(function() {
        // Get the selected value from dropdown1
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
          sessionStorage.setItem("selected_Value", selectedValue);
          selected_Value = sessionStorage.getItem("selected_Value");
     
         setTimeout(function() {  
             // Set the selected value to dropdown2
             $('input[name="start_time[0]"]').val(selected_Value);
        var abc =  $('select#start-time-selector_0').find('option[value="selected_Value"]');
        $("select#start-time-selector_0 > option").each(function() {
         if(this.value == selected_Value){
     alert(this.text);
         //   alert(this.value);
         //   $('#start-time-selector_0 option[value="(this.value"]').trigger('click');
          $('#start-time-selector_0 option[data-id="'+this.text+'"]').trigger('change');
         }
}); 
          }, 20000);
      }); 

 
  });
 </script>
```

by using above code I can get value of text and value both of from drop-down but it is not trigger into popup drop-down. I have selected time 1 pm so I am getting `value = 5532` so this value should change and time also need to set 1 pm instead of default time

website Video for your reference : https://app.screencast.com/fSOLyLn7KhUZJ

if anyone can give me solution then it will be great help to me.

Thanks

I have tried different js on change dropdown value and I have also tried to directly add time into span like 1 pm but that not worked for me. I have tried below jQuery but not any worked for be above is worked but not completely

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
require([
'jquery',
'domReady!'
], function ($)
 {
 
    $('#popup-open').change(function() {
        // Get the selected value from dropdown1
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();

         var homeselectedval = $('#select2-start-time-container').html();
         sessionStorage.setItem("selected_Value", homeselectedval);
                    // startTimeSelectClass = '.start-time-select',
         selected_Value = sessionStorage.getItem("selected_Value");
                 alert(homeselectedval);
          setTimeout(function() { 
                 alert(selected_Value);
             // Set the selected value to dropdown2
             $('#start-time-selector_0').val(selected_Value);
           }, 20000);
      }); 
 
  });
 </script>


 <script type="text/javascript">  
require([
'jquery',
'domReady!'
], function ($)
 {
 
    $('#start-time').change(function() {
        // Get the selected value from dropdown1
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
         sessionStorage.setItem("selected_Value", selectedValue);
                    // startTimeSelectClass = '.start-time-select',
         selected_Value = sessionStorage.getItem("selected_Value");
               alert(selected_Value );
         setTimeout(function() { 
          alert(selected_Value );
             // Set the selected value to dropdown2
             $('input[name="start_time[0]"]').val(selected_Value);
          }, 20000);
      }); 
  });
 </script>

<script type="text/javascript">  
require([
'jquery',
'domReady!'
], function ($)
 {
 
    $('#start-time').change(function() {
        // Get the selected value from dropdown1
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
           var homeselectedval =  $('#select2-start-time-container').html();
       sessionStorage.setItem("selected_Value", selectedValue);
       sessionStorage.setItem("textval", homeselectedval );

                   // startTimeSelectClass = '.start-time-select',
         selected_Value = sessionStorage.getItem("selected_Value");
         textval = sessionStorage.getItem("textval");
               alert(selected_Value );
               alert(textval);
         setTimeout(function() { 
             alert(selected_Value );
            alert(textval);
             // Set the selected value to dropdown2
             $('input[name="start_time[0]"]').val(selected_Value);
             $('select2-start-time-selector_0-container]').val(textval);
 
          }, 20000);
      }); 

 
  });
 </script>`
```

Comment: Why do you have the same code pasted in multiple times? Is this a copy/paste error or just bad code?  You appear to be trying to "fix" something with the `setTimeout(function() { ` which usually means something is wrong in the code.

Comment: try  : `$("#start-time-selector_0").select2("val", selected_Value);` and remove the `setTimeout`

Comment: FWIW not trying to be negative but this whole set of code is kind of a mess.  Undeclared variables, inconsistent naming, multiple `<script` tags  variables used out of scope etc.